# longdiv macro without answers

Tags: math-mode, macros

This code (using [longiv](https://ctan.org/pkg/longdiv)) produces

```
\documentclass{article} 
\input{longdiv} 
\begin{document}
\longdiv{52}{2}
\end{document}
```

[image: As is output]

I'd like to replace the answers with _s.  Can anyone suggest the right way to achieve this.
[image: Desired output]

If there is another package that can do the same or provide better control like how many steps are shown etc.,  it will be good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my attempt. I modified the code from [`longdiv.tex`](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/generic/misc/longdiv.tex) and created `\examlongdiv`. I assume that you won’t use this to scare away your students so numbers greater than 999 999 999 are not supported. `;-)`

Perhaps some explanations are needed. My approach is essentially:

> Replacing each digit with a dash.

The details are

1. Measure the natural width of a single digit, say `\digitwidth`. This width is used to determine the length of the replacement dash. The white space on both sides of the dash can be adjusted by changing `\digitspace`.
2. The number of digits is stored in the counter `\numofdigits`. This gives the number of dashes needed to replace the intermediate quotients and remainders.
3. Use `\loop` to draw as many `\digitdash`’s as needed.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\input{longdiv}

\newlength\digitwidth
\settowidth\digitwidth{$0$}
\newcommand*\digitspace{0.05em}
\newcommand*\digitdash{%
  \hspace*{\digitspace}%
  \rule{\dimexpr\digitwidth-\digitspace-\digitspace\relax}{0.4pt}%
  \hspace*{\digitspace}%
}
\newcount\numofdigits
\newcommand*\getnumofdigits[1]{%
  \ifnum#1<10 1\else
  \ifnum#1<100 2\else
  \ifnum#1<1000 3\else
  \ifnum#1<10000 4\else
  \ifnum#1<100000 5\else
  \ifnum#1<1000000 6\else
  \ifnum#1<10000000 7\else
  \ifnum#1<100000000 8\else
    9%
  \fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi
}
\newcommand*\examlongdiv[2]{%
 \vtop{\normalbaselines \offinterlineskip
   \setbox\strutbox\hbox{\vrule height 2.1ex depth .5ex width0ex}%
   \def\showdig{%
      $\numofdigits=\getnumofdigits{\the\LDscratch}%
       \underline{%
         \loop
         \ifnum\numofdigits>0
           \digitdash
         \advance\numofdigits -1 %
         \repeat
       \strut}$\cr
       \numofdigits=\getnumofdigits{\the\rtot}%
       \loop
       \ifnum\numofdigits>0
         \digitdash
       \advance\numofdigits -1 %
       \repeat
       \strut\cr
       \noalign{\kern-.2ex}}%
   \global\rtot=#1\relax
   \count0=\rtot\divide\count0by#2\edef\quotient{\the\count0}%\show\quotient
   % make list macro out of digits in quotient:
   \def\temp##1{\ifx##1\temp\else \noexpand\dodig ##1\expandafter\temp\fi}%
   \edef\routine{\expandafter\temp\quotient\temp}%
   % process list to give power-of-ten:
   \def\dodig##1{\global\multiply\gpten by10 }\global\gpten=1 \routine
   % to display effect of one digit in quotient (zero ignored):
   \def\dodig##1{\global\divide\gpten by10
      \LDscratch =\gpten
      \multiply\LDscratch  by##1%
      \multiply\LDscratch  by#2%
      \global\advance\rtot-\LDscratch \relax
      \ifnum\LDscratch>0 \showdig \fi % must hide \cr in a macro to skip it
   }%
   \tabskip=0pt
   \halign{\hfil##\cr % \halign for entire division problem
     $\numofdigits=\getnumofdigits{\quotient}%
      \loop
      \ifnum\numofdigits>0
        \digitdash
      \advance\numofdigits -1 %
      \repeat$\strut\cr
     #2$\,\overline{\vphantom{\big)}%
     \hbox{\smash{\raise3.5\fontdimen8\textfont3\hbox{$\big)$}}}%
     \mkern2mu \the\rtot}$\cr\noalign{\kern-.2ex}
     \routine \cr % do each digit in quotient
}}}

\begin{document}
\examlongdiv{52}{2}
\examlongdiv{987654321}{26}
\end{document}
```

[image: exam long division]